# How to create Subtheme of Omega while Omega Tools and Drush both has some disclaimer and Moved to Github?

Tags: drush, theming

I am a beginner in Drupal. I am using Drupal 7.

I wanted to create Subtheme in [Omega.](https://www.drupal.org/project/omega)
Theses are the [methods to create subtheme](https://www.drupal.org/node/819170) (With Omega Tools, Drush and Manually)in Omega.

I have install new core [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal) and installed Omega in my
sites/all/themes folder.
So, path for this would be:

"../sites/all/themes/omega"

I followed this [Tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/node/1298672) to create Subtheme using Omega Tools (As this is recommended for Beginners).
[Omega Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/omega_tools) is one of the [Recommended Modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/1298616) to create sub theme with Omega.

In Omega Tools there is one **DISCLAIMER:**

"**DISCLAIMER:** Do **not** use Omega Tools with the 4.x version of Omega. Please

- **create your 4.x subthemes using Drush!**

  The Drush integration for Omega 4.x comes as part of the theme itself and does NOT require Omega Tools. Please uninstall Omega Tools if you are building a site with Omega 4.x."

So, this message leads me to the [Drush](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush) where I saw the [Drush project has moved to Github.](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush)

And theses are the [Release Notes.](https://www.drupal.org/node/97249/release)

I read that we can also create sub theme with [this method](https://www.drupal.org/node/1298682).

- But how can I install Drush while [Drush has been moved to Github?](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush) as I wanted to use Omega Tools to harness the full power of Omega.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm speculating a bit, but Drush surely moved to github from the project page on d.o because it simply isn't a module. It is:

> a command-line shell and scripting interface for Drupal

So if you're thinking it's a module that needs be installed and enabled in your site, it isn't. It's a separate utility that needs to be installed on your machine.

You're absolutely right to want to stick with getting it installed for working with Omega, it does make life a lot easier. You can do so by following the detailed instructions on the [github page](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush).

There are also a bunch of questions in the [composer](/questions/tagged/composer) tag that should help if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

@Clive: First of all thanks for the useful information. As I am new to Drupal, I thought it was a module but thanks for clearing my doubts.

Yes, Drush is an amazing tool even though installing Drush for the first time is such a pain.

Here is some informations that might be helpful for those who might stuck like me in the future.
I followed tutorial from [this site](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/ssh/) to install Drush.

It is really very easy to create subtheme in omega using [Drush](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush).
How to [create subtheme in Omega](https://www.drupal.org/node/1298676).

File structure for the Subtheme is in:
sites/all/themes OR sites/all/themes/omega.

These two links were also helpful to me to create subtheme:

1. [Overview of Theme Files](https://www.drupal.org/node/171194)
2. [Creating a Subtheme](https://www.drupal.org/node/225125)

Thanks!